# Change anonymous class to static

Tags: java, android

The following code shows me the following error:

"Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static"

How can I fix it?

```
private void showGameOverDialog(final int messageId) {
        // DialogFragment to display game stats and start new game
        final DialogFragment gameResult =
                new DialogFragment() { //**error in this place**
                    // create an AlertDialog and return it
                    @Override
                    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
                        // create dialog displaying String resource for messageId
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(messageId));

                        // display number of shots fired and total time elapsed
                        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.results_format, shotsFired, totalElapsedTime));
                        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_game,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    // called when "Reset Game" Button is pressed

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) {
                                        dialogIsDisplayed = false;
                                        newGame(); // set up and start a new game
                                    }
                                }
                        );

                        return builder.create(); // return the AlertDialog
                    }
                };

        // in GUI thread, use FragmentManager to display the DialogFragment
        activity.runOnUiThread(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        showSystemBars();
                        dialogIsDisplayed = true;
                        gameResult.setCancelable(false); // modal dialog
                        gameResult.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "results");
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`new SomeType(args) {` <-- that is an 'anonymous class' declaration, and what that error is complaining about. That's because such code is shorthand.

Let's say you have:

```
class Example {
   void foo() {
     new Object() {
       void foo() {}
     };
   }
}
```

Then that's just shorthand for:

```
class Example {
   void foo() {
     class MyObject$1 {
       void foo() {}
     }

     new MyObject$1();
   }
}
```

In other words, you're defining a class just the same, just - with an irrelevant name as you'll only ever instantiate it right on the very line. But you're still defining a class.

All classes that are either [A] 'local' (inside a method declaration) or [B] inside a class *and* not marked `static`, are a bit magical: They have a secret field that you don't see, of the outer type. That's because  instances of such inner classes are deemed to exist within the context of an instance of the outer (encompassing) class, and that context is stored in that hidden field. That's why you can invoke instance methods from your outer class inside an inner class, as well as interact with fields. But which instance are you invoking this in? Well, on that 'magical' invisible field.

This is all rather complicated, and it makes recovery from frozen states difficult, hence that warning.

The simple solution is to never have such classes with magical fields inside them. To accomplish this:

- **always** mark any classes that you write inside classes as `static`.
- Do not ever declare any class inside any method.
- Do not use the `new X() {` syntax, ever.

Those are ... rather onerous limitations. You can still write 'functions' using lambda syntax but I'm not sure android supports it (android is more or less frozen in time, 10+ years in the past or so, before lambda syntax existed in java the language). But that's what the error is telling you you can't do.

You'd have to do something like:

```java
class TheClassThatCodeYouPastedIsIn {
  private static class MyClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    // called when "Reset Game" Button is pressed

    private final TheClassThatCodeYouPastedIsIn instance;
    MyClickListener(TheClassThatCodeYouPastedIsIn instance) {
      this.instance = instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      dialogIsDisplayed = false;
      instance.newGame(); // set up and start a new game
    }
  }

  private void showGameOverDialog(final int messageId) {
    // ... rest of the code.

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_game, new MyClickListener(this));
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: In Java 18 that field will be [omitted if it is not used](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/18-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8271623). Not that it matters for Android through.